# USSD secure or not?

Tags: security, encryption, gsm, ussd, usrp

I have a question about USSD and security in this channel.

As you know today mobile banking and many payments using USSD, I want to know is USSD safe?

If USSD transactions using a5/1 for encryption,its totally broke few years a go and now can be captured by usrp (or HackRF board) and decoded by rainbow tables created for a5/1.

I think this transactions is not really safe,but I want to know more about this protocol and encryption using at this transactions. I dont know USSD codes encoded with a5/1 or GSM-7... so my question is:

1. What is encryption using for USSD transactions? Is the USSD using
   GSM voice encryption ( a5/1) or using GSM-7 or other?
2. How we can make USSD secure? is possible to add additional
   encryption to transactions or what you think about securing USSD
   codes and transactions.

Thanks all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: This is not programming, but deep in security.

Answer (score 10):

In general there are two level of security in Mobile networks (in this case GSM)

1. AirInterface Security
2. Core Network Security

For the AirInterface (Radio Interface between MS and BTS) it can be encrypted or unencrypted (depend on network setting)

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/2
```

As you can see both current encryption methods are so weak specially for financial transaction (compare to acceptable encryption methods for online banking).

The real problem for USSD messages are their MAP/SS7(Sigtran) related message in the core network.
Unfortunately all USSD messages in GSM network transfer as a plain text (as a part of MAP message) and all E1 links are easily monitor-able.

Using USSD as a transmission layer (in the lack of Data connection(GPRS-3G-LTE)on network) is possible but an encryption layer is require ( and it can be implemented on Android or IOS App)

Comment: thanks for your helps... A5/2 is not secure really but A5/1 a little secure and used in all operators now in worldwide, but as you know its breakable in a less than minutes... is USSD messages use voice channel to send and receive messages? so if yes the commands should be encrypted using A5/1, is using a unique band, what is this and what is the encryption using for this commands? I think using USSD using GSM 7 encoding, but its really unsafe and breakable with a simple JS code.. for securing USSD command, only way is using app on phone? I dont want using any application..

Comment: There are two different radio signal in GSM networks.The one which is used for Traffic(Call) and another part which is used for signaling , after establishing the call , both part transmit on the same channel. USSD and SMS are using(transferring) on signaling part. therefore USSD is not over the voice. Even TDMF is transferred on signaling part. Please check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gsm/gsm_security.htm for more detail.

Comment: _USSD and SMS are using(transferring) on signaling part. therefore USSD is not over the voice._ Does it mean that SMS and USSD messages are transmitted in plaintext between handset and BTS?